# How to SELECT for Value Mark Characters in TCL?

Tags: universe, u2, pick

I am doing a `SELECT` in TCL for UniVerse. I want to see if there are any value marks in a given field. Is there way to represent a value mark character in my TCL `SELECT`?

I know there are reserved variables in PICK, such as value mark `@VM`, representing the ASCII 253 character.

I have something like this already:

```
SELECT SOMEFILE WITH DICT7 = "[SUBSTRING]"
```

I want something like this using the appropriate reserved word for value marks:

```
SELECT SOMEFILE WITH DICT7 = "[@VM]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to test a Field to see if contains any Value Marks, you can do this.

```
SELECT SOMEFILE WITH EVAL "COUNT(DICT7,@VM)" GT 0
```

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for! I knew about I-descriptors as part of indexes, but didn't know about EVAL parsing a string as an I-descriptor. This let's me do straight TCL without having to build a dictionary or index.

Comment: It should be noted that using EVAL does technically update the dictionary file, but not in a way that you can see with LIST DICT. I believe the compiled I-DESC code lives in there somewhere and I have been told that there are shops where using EVAL is frowned upon for that reason. Personally, I probably overuse it. Gleefully.